# rails wicked gem redirect_to with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'am struggling with adding a parameter to redirect_to using wicked
I followed the Railscast and read the information on the github page but can't get it to work.
I want to create a object plugin and after it is saved there should be the possibility to add stuff to it.

Here is what i got:

plugins_controller:

```
def create
  @plugin = Plugin.new(params[:plugin])
  if @plugin.save
    redirect_to plugins_steps_path, :plugin_id => @plugin.id
  end
end
```

plugins_steps controller:

```
def show
  @plugin = Plugin.find(params[:plugin_id])
  render_wizard
end
```

routes:

```
resources :plugins_steps
```

I never get any parameter to the show method in plugins_steps is there a way to solve this?
I also tried several redirect_to methods like:

```
redirect_to :controller: "plugins_steps", :action => "show", :plugin_id => @plugin.id
```

or

```
redirect_to({:plugin_id => @plugin.id })
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plugins_steps_path` is the path for the index action.  If you want the show action, use `plugin_step_path` (i.e. **step** must be singular).  Run `rake routes` to verify this.
Also, instead of calling the param `:plugin_id`, just use `:id` and update your show controller accordingly.

Comment: Thx for your response. In the mean time I 'solved' it with putting the plugin object into the session, so that it can be accessed during the whole creation process. But I am not sure if this is a good way?

Comment: It's not recommended to store data in the session, other than the id.  That way, if you modify database tables, the session will automatically reflect the new schema instead of containing stale information.  It's also a security risk, since the client has access to the session and can modify it.  The solution I gave you uses the standard Rails approach to doing what you want to do, so it's really the best solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining to me really appreciate it.